# Show Different columns on selection of dropdown in jqGrid

Tags: php, jquery, jqgrid

I just followed this but mine is in php,
[Show different Jqgrid formats in the same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7641918/show-different-jqgrid-formats-in-the-same-page) i also want same kind of options if i select a item from dropdown all columns want to hide except few,particularly i not understood this and how to write this code in `php`

```
<table width="100%">
<tr>
<td>Tipo de Equipo :</td>
<td><% =Html.DropDownList("TipoId", (SelectList)ViewData["tiposdeEquipo"], "--Seleccione--", new { @id = "displaydropdown" })%> </td> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Mostrar" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

how this code works by clicking that `Mostrar` ,please help me i'm a beginner.

This is my code

```
<select id="displaydropdown" name="displaydropdown">
<option selected>Change Type</option>
<option value="A">option1</option>
<option value="B">option2</option>
<option value="C">option3</option>
</select>

<div class="box A" align="center"><table id="jqGrid" ></table><div id="jqGridPager"></div></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

var lastsel;

$(function () {
        $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
        url:'server.php',
        editurl: 'update.php',
        datatype: "json",
        shrinkToFit: true,
        colModel:[
            {label:'COUNT',name:'ID',align:"center"},
            {label:'EMPLOYEE LOGIN',name:'Employee_Login',align:"center"},
            {label:'NEW LEAD',name:'New_Value',align:"center"},
            {label:'REASON/COMMENTS',name:'Requestor_NOTES',align:"center"},
            {label:'EXISTING LEAD',name:'Existing_Value',align:"center"},
                ],              
        rowNum:200,
        rowList:[400,300,200],
        onCellSelect: function (rowid, iCol, cellcontent, e) {
            if (rowid && rowid !== lastsel) {
                $('#jqGrid').restoreRow(lastsel);
                lastsel = rowid;
            }
        $('#jqGrid').editRow(rowid, true, iCol);
            },
        pager: '#jqGridPager',
        sortorder: "asc",
        viewrecords: true,
        height:'300px',
        width:'750'

    });
    jQuery("#jqGrid").jqGrid('navGrid',"#jqGridPager",{edit:false,add:false,del:false,search:false});
    //$('#jqGrid').jqGrid('setGridWidth', '1300');
    });

    $("#displaydropdown").change(function () {
        var display = $("#displaydropdown option:selected").val();
        if (display == 'A') 
        {
            $('#jqGrid').hideCol('ID');
            $('#jqGrid').showCol('Req_Date');
            $('#jqGrid').showCol('App_WeekBeginning');

        }
        else if (display == 'B') {
            $('#jqGrid').hideCol('App_WeekBeginning');
            $('#jqGrid').showCol('Req_Day' );
            $('#jqGrid').showCol('App_Week');

        }
        else if (display == 'C') {
            $('#jqGrid').hideCol('App_Week')
            $('#jqGrid').showCol('ID');
            $('#jqGrid').showCol('Req_Date');
        }
    });



</script>
```

Comment: Which problem exactly you have (what is not work)? The code `jQuery(document).ready(function () {...});` and `$(function () {...});` do **the same**: you should don't place one waiting for document ready inside of another one. Which format have the data returned from `url:'server.php'` (an example with 2-3 rows would be helpful)? You should never use `name` property in `colModel` with the values which contains spaces (like `'NEW LEAD'`) or special characters `name:'EXISTING LEAD'`. It's bad to use `index` properties. Probably you want to use `label: 'EMPLOYEE LOGIN', name: 'Req_Date'`?

Comment: It's important to include in every question about jqGrid the information, which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). Another common remark: I'd recommend you to look at [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34976517/315935), which shows an example of calling `editRow` and `restoreRow` inside of `beforeSelectRow` and `onSelectRow` and the usage of `savedRow` parameter instead of `lastsel`.

Comment: Thanks @Oleg for reply, i will rename to Label from name. i'm using [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103292) ,

Comment: You are welcome! I develop [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) fork and recommend you to take a look in it. The basic information is described [here](http://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html). Free jqGrid code is compatible to old jqGrid 4.x and the most features described in [the old documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jqgriddocs) works in free jqGrid. New features are described in [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki) and READMEs to every published version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The methods `showCol` and `hideCol` should use the value of `name` property from `colModel` and not the value of `index` property, like in your current code. Moreover the `name` property will be used to build `id` of some internal jqGrid elements. Thus value of the `name` property should have no spaces, which are prohibited in HTML5 (see [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute)). I suppose that you wanted to use

```
{label:'EMPLOYEE LOGIN',name:'Req_Date',align:"center"}
```

for example, instead of

```
{name:'EMPLOYEE LOGIN',index:'Req_Date',align:"center"}
```

After the changes the code `$('#jqGrid').showCol('Req_Date');` should work.

Comment: ,i have this stupid doubt ,assume in my mysql database i have table with 3 columns `ID` ,`FIRSTNAME` ,`LASTNAME` . how to use this columns names to fetch data using jqGrid. i thought using `name` keyword in `colModel`.

Comment: and can you check my code i edited it.. is it correct

Comment: @SunilSharma: Is your code work now? Can you hide/show columns? The names of the columns of the tables in the database could have no relation to the format of the data, which you return from the server. I asked you in my first comment: **Which format have the data returned from url:'server.php' (an example with 2-3 rows would be helpful)?**. How many total rows you want to display (100, 1000, 10000, 1000000)? Your current code don't use `loadonce: true` options, thus you probably have implemented **server side** paging and sorting of data. Is it so?